# Search different words together

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

```
 public string getSearchResult(string qry, string options, string noOfRecords, string strrefine)
 {
     string Query = "";
     if (qry == "") return "";
     string[] qrymod = qry.Split(' ');
     if (qrymod.Length > 1)
     {
         for (int i=1; qrymod.Length > i; i++)
         {
             qry =qrymod[i];
         }
     }

     //qry = qrymod[0];
     qry = qry.Replace("\\", "\\\\").Replace("%", "\\%").Replace("_", "\\_");
     if (options == "A" || options == "AC")
        Query += " Select top " + noOfRecords + " cast(activityid as nvarchar(50)) as 'id',title as 'title',cast(description as varchar(200)) as 'desc' ,'AC' as 'Type' from searchActivity WHERE title like '%" + chkText(qry) + "%' or description like '%" + chkText(qry) + "%'  escape '\\' ";
}
```

I can perform search from this function but the issue is whenever i am entering the text with two words 
it searches the word after entering space the function will start searching the 2nd word 
i want to compile the search result  to search both the words

Comment: for (int i=1; qrymod.Length > i; i++)
            {

                 qry =qrymod[i];
            }
The i here starts at '1' always, then how can you have the first word?

Comment: it searches the first word also , but after entering space the previous search result disappears as the qrymod get the value of the second string , it start searching the new word entering after space , the issue is i want the previous word search and the new one both

Comment: let me say if i have a sentence like 

A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy cat

if i search quick cat 

i want it highlight both the words but first it shows the quick word highlighted after that it highlight the Cat word 

i want the both

Answer (score 1):

You want to do a full text query... Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx)